# Android image capture from web page link using uri scheme

Tags: android, uri

I'm trying to open up my Camera using a URI scheme from a web page link:

```
android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

I can get Skype:  and tel: to work but I can't seem to get an image/* to work.

e.g. this works

```
tel:555-1013
```

this doesn't work

```
image/*android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I'm trying to use this method as I'm using Axure which doesn't allow me "under the hood" to add my own complete Intent details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is an example of HTML5 code that can be used to get image from phone gallery or take picture using phone camera. Just tested it on Nexus 4 Running android 4.2.2 and it works fine:

http://html5.merge.nl/file-api.php

Following is the screen shot from Nexus 7 running android 4.2.1

[image]

Following is the html of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>HTML5 / File API</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.merge.nl/sites/all/themes/merge/images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.merge.nl/sites/all/themes/merge/images/favicon.ico" />


<body>

<section id="wrapper">

    <header>
      <h1>HTML5  / File API</h1>
    </header>

<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="file" accept="image/*">  



</form>

<hr>
Your User-Agent:
<br>
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks but it didn't launch the camera for me. Also, using the Input file type wont work (I think) because I can't add the 'accept="image/*"' in Axure. That's why I'm looking for a URI scheme because I can modify that.

Comment: which device are you using? which android version?

Comment: uploaded the screen shot... never used Axure so not sure about that.. but the above is the standard way of doing this using HTML5...